# How does zero knowledge proof prevent frontrunning

Tags: protocol, zero-knowledge, frontrunning

I have learned about that zkp can hide the information of orders, e.g. the type and the number of assets, but it's still confusing. Is there any paper or project about using zero-knowledge proof to prevent front-running?